# Where in maven project's path should I put configuration files that are not considered resources

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I have a simple java maven project. One of my classes when executing needs to load an xml configuration file from the classpath. I don't want to package such xml file when producing the jar but I want to include a default xml file in a zip assembly under a conf subfolder and I also want this default xml to be available in the unit tests to test against it.

As I see it there are 2 possible places of this default xml:

1. `src/main/resources/conf/default.xml`
2. `src/main/conf/default.xml`

Both solutions demand special pom actions:

- In solution 1, I get the auto copy to target folder during build which means it is available in testing but I also get it in the produced jar which i don't want.
- In solution 2, I get the jar as I want it(free of the xml) but I manually have to copy the xml to the target folder to be available for testing. (I don't want to add src's subfolders in test classpath. I think it is bad practice).

**Question: what is the best solution of the two?**
- If the correct is 2, what is the best way to copy it to target folder?
- Is there any other solution better and more common than those two?

(I also read [Where should I put application configuration files for a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465001/where-should-i-put-application-configuration-files-for-a-maven-project) but I would like to know the most "correct solution" from the "convention over configuration" point of view and this link provides some configuration type solutions but not any convention oriented. Maybe there isn't one but I ask anyway. Also the solutions provided include AntRun plugin and appAssembler plugin and I wonder if I could do it with out them.)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

> The question is what is the best solution of the two? If the correct is 2, what is the best way to copy it to target folder? Is there any other solution better and more common than those two?

Since you want that file to be copied to the `target/classes` folder, it has somehow to be considered as a resource (so either put in under `src/main/resources` or declare `src/main/conf` as resource directory). And if you don't want it in the final jar, configure the [Maven JAR Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) to exclude it:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/conf/*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

For the assembly part, assembly descriptors are pretty flexible so it should be possible to achieve what you want regardless of the choice. I'd suggest using the easiest setup though.

Comment: There are problems with both solutions: 1./ declaring 'conf' as a resource still includes it in the jar, and leaves us no easy way of excluding; 2./ creating 'conf' inside resources, and excluding it in the plugin causes it not to be at the root of the class path.

Comment: for some reason this is one of the few useful answers in general for "how to exclude something from maven jar" when googling... even if it doesn't answer OP exactly, it's still a great example of using `maven-jar-plugin`

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to use two profiles: Development (default) and Packaging

My default / section contains both src/main/resources and src/main/conf. I call this my Development profile, which is an implicit profile.

My packaging profile is an explicit profile which is defined under  section. There under / I only mentioned src/main/resources. When I'm running my packaging script (we currently have this external to maven since its building an RPM out of our WAR), I'm running 'mvn install -Drpm' to activate my Packaging profile (rpm is the id for the Packaging profile.

If this wasn't clear enough, feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking. My packaging phase copies configuration from `src/main/resources` and then excludes this directory in the compiled JAR. But during development, I still need my `/src/main/resources` so that I can run locally... It is a conundrum I've been in for awhile now and I think this is my answer. It's old but still very relevant!

Answer (score 1):

You could place it in src/test/conf/default.xml. Your testclasses can find it, but it wont be packaged using the standard method.

With an additional assembly you can package it from there. That step is always necessary.

A different solution could be to create a separate maven module and place it in /src/main/resources/conf/... .Then make this jar a test dependency. You do not need to do any special plugin configuration, but I think it is overkill for a single file.

Comment: The thing i dont like with this solution is that the assembly producing the zip will need to get it from src/test/conf and this xml is not only a test file. I assume your proposed solution is the same if I instead put it in src/main/conf? From there it is also visible to tests from the target/classes folder instead of target/test-classes. Is it wrong to do tests that get data from target/classes or should they depend only in target/test-classes?

Answer (score 0):

If your packaging is **war**, you can use the [packagingExcudes](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html) configuration option of the [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/index.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Exclude abc.properties found in src/main/resources/ (ends up getting packaged in WEB-INF/classes/) -->
          <packagingExcludes>
            WEB-INF/classes/abc.properties
          </packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Use commas to separate between multiple resources you want to exclude. Also, you can use wildcards and regex in your excluded paths. For regex, it's in the `%regex[YOUR_REGEX_HERE]` syntax. Check the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html) for more details.