# In Maven how to exclude resources from the generated jar?

Tags: maven

When I create an executable jar with dependencies (using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814526/problem-building-executable-jar-with-maven/1814697#1814697)), all properties files are packaged into that jar too. How to stop it from happening? Thanks.

UPDATE: I tried to exclude them using the [Maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html), but then my application won't find the properties files when I run it in Eclipse (right click on the module -> Run As -> Java Application)

UPDATE: Thanks for your useful answers. I think I'd better spend time to learn Maven, for now I just choose the simplest solution.

Comment: Could you be more precise about these resources? Why do you want to exclude them from the JAR? When do you need them?

Comment: I want to exclude them because they store the application's configurations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put those properties files in `src/test/resources`. Files in `src/test/resources` are available within Eclipse automatically via `eclipse:eclipse` but will not be included in the packaged JAR by Maven.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a simple solution. I wish I could accept all answers here.

Comment: This is a bad answer as it is Eclipse specific, relying on an inability for Eclipse to implement separate classpaths for main and test. Other IDEs have separate classpaths, and so your code won't work in those IDEs. Hopefully Eclipse will have separate classpaths at some point too.

Comment: Be sure to define build/outputDirectory to be different from Eclipse's  default output folder, otherwise a jar built from mvn command line might include stuff Eclipse has put there (eg contents of src/test/resources)

Comment: So where do you actual test resources go?

Comment: Generally speaking this is also a bad answer as it requires changing the setup given in the question. Maybe one needs their stuff in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: see my answer below -- this is a great time to use the `Maven JAR plugin`

Comment: While the mention of eclipse is correct, I don't believe that the src/test/resources path is specific to eclipse, but rather a convention that maven follows by default.  So, if you're using maven to build that solution will work regardless of which IDE you're using.

Answer (score 136):

To exclude any file from a jar / target directory you can use the `<excludes>` tag in your pom.xml file.

In the next example, all files with `.properties` extension will not be included:

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3004684/363573) provides, in my opinion, a more elegant way to exclude unwanted resources with maven jar plugin.

Comment: If I am not wrong, there is a problem with this solution, because it exclude these files from all the plugins. How about just excluding them from assembly plugin? I have tried the same configuration inside the configuration tag in the plugin tag, and it doesn't work

Comment: Damior consider editing your answer. @AfshinMoazami has a solid point. The other answer linked by Stephan is more structured / reliable / accurate

Comment: This will exclue them even when IDEA make the module, I only want to exclude it when package, how?

Answer (score 19):

By convention, the directory `src/main/resources` contains the resources that will be used by the application. So Maven will include them in the final `JAR`.

Thus in your application, you will access them using the `getResourceAsStream()` method, as the resources are loaded in the classpath.

If you need to have them outside your application, do not store them in `src/main/resources` as they will be bundled by Maven. Of course, you can exclude them (using the link given by *chkal*) but it is better to create another directory (for example `src/main/external-resources`) in order to keep the conventions regarding the `src/main/resources` directory.

In the latter case, you will have to deliver the resources independently as your JAR file (this can be achieved by using the Assembly plugin). If you need to access them in your Eclipse environment, go to the `Properties` of your project, then in `Java Build Path` in `Sources` tab, add the folder (for example `src/main/external-resources`). Eclipse will then add this directory in the classpath.

Comment: I think I'm doing things wrong. Perhaps `src/main/resources` is not a place to put the application's configurations. I have a difficult situation in which I haven't known how to write unit tests yet.

Comment: To be OK with conventions, one can use the maven jar plugin. See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3004684/363573

Comment: src/main/resources is the default maven convention used to put resources, however another convention maven uses is that test property resources should go in src/test/resources.  Anything placed there won't get packaged with a deliverable jar, when building in maven.

Comment: This is the answer that gave me the best insight and allowed me to understand how to correctly structure my project.

Answer (score 16):

This calls exactly for the using the [Maven JAR Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/)

For example, if you want to exclude everything under `src/test/resources/` from the final jar, put this:

```
<build>

        <plugins>
            <!-- configure JAR build -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>src/test/resources/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

...
```

Files under `src/test/resources/` will still be available on class-path, they just won't be in resulting JAR.

Comment: `<exclude>src/test/resources/**</exclude>` doesn't work. Exclude will be applied on jar final path and should be `<exclude>*.properties</exclude>`

Answer (score 11):

Exclude specific pattern of file during creation of maven jar using maven-jar-plugin.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
      <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
      <exclude>**/*.exe</exclude>
      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
      <exclude>**/*.xls</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean to property files located in `src/main/resources`? Then you should exclude them using the maven-resource-plugin. See the following page for details:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

Comment: But then my application can't find the properties files when I run it in Eclipse (right click on the module -> Run As -> Java Application)

Comment: You could add a separate Maven profile for the generation of the executable JAR and exclude the property files on there.

Comment: rather than exclude the directory entirely, OP wants to exclude them when the JAR is being made. So it makes more sense to use `maven-jar-plug` and exclude within there. Like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001713/where-in-maven-projects-path-should-i-put-configuration-files-that-are-not-cons?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use the [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), e.g. to exclude a logging properties file used only locally in your IDE:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-shade-plugin-version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>log4j2.xml</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will however exclude the files from every artifact, so it might not be feasible in every situation.

Answer (score 0):

> When I create an executable jar with dependencies (using this guide), all properties files are packaged into that jar too. How to stop it from happening? Thanks.

Properties files from where? Your main jar? Dependencies?

In the former case, putting resources under `src/test/resources` as suggested is probably the most straight forward and simplest option.

In the later case, you'll have to create a custom assembly descriptor with special `excludes/exclude` in the [`unpackOptions`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_unpackOptions).

Answer (score 0):

here is [another solution](https://www.kianworknotes.com/2019/12/how-to-exclude-all-files-in-resources.html) to **exclude all files in resources folder**, the final configuration looks like:

```
<build>
    <!-- exclude all files in resources-->    
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <!-- other configurations/plugins in the pom.xml-->
</build>
```

or we can [use includes](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) to only package some file or folder.
But this method has a side effect. IDE will also exclude the resource files in `target/classes` folder. **maven-jar-plugin** only affect jar file.

I found a better solution to execludes resourses folder using **maven-jar-plugin**, here we use **includes**:

```
<build>

        <plugins>
            <!-- configure JAR build -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.class</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

...
```