# How to exclude certain resources from archived jar when archiveClasses=true

Tags: maven

I have following maven plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- This puts everything under /WEB-INF/classes into a jar under WEB-INF/lib -->
        <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <!-- This contains the configuration files that Iwant to keep separate from the JAR.. from /src/main/resources-->
                <directory>src/main/myconfig</directory>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
            </resource>      
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However I want to exclude certain .properties file from the archive jar file enabled in

```
<archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
```

***So I want to exclude the properties file from archived jar, but not from war file (still expected under WEB-INF/classes***

how to make it happen?

Comment: take the java tag off this, theres no java here

Comment: I think this link explains how it can be done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113697/in-maven-how-to-exclude-resources-from-the-generated-jar