# How to exclude file from dependent jar when running sprint boot app?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jar, pom.xml

I want to exclude a specific file from the base jar while running my project (which will use the base jar as dependency)

Base project structure looks like:-

```
baselib
|
|----src
|     |
|     |--some packages
|     |
|     |--resources
|          | -- somefile.xml      
|     
|---target
```

Another project called "**mycustomproject**" will have "**baselib**" as dependency jar in pom.xml

My question i,s how to debug/run (Debug As/Run As-> Spring Boot App) the "mycustomproject" by excluding "**somefile.xm**l" alone. I cannot remove this file in "baselib" since some one is using it.

Could someone share some inputs here?

Comment: I understand you are using maven, right? You can use the resource configuration in the pom or the resources . plugin check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5663653/2598606

Comment: simplest solution is not to add that file in  the `src/main/resources` directory. ? Apart from that I don't understand your question..?

Comment: @kiuby_88 : Thx for the reply. Yes I am using maven. I tried that solution already but no luck. And that configuration will execute when building our solution right? I am sure that, the xml is not excluded when running my project. Any idea?

Comment: @khmarbaise: Hi, Thx for the reply. That lib is used by some one else too. So modification over there will impact.  Any idea? Thx.

Comment: If you like to prevent that file in the jar you have to remove it from the project and rebuild....