# Using Maven, how can a child module inherit the parent module's repository?

Tags: java, mysql, node.js, spring, maven

Currently my web app has a spring-boot/java backend and an angular5/node frontend. I am using a Maven wrapper to encapsulate the projects such that the backend and frontend are both linked via the parent pom.

I am now configuring my database and I am putting the repository information in the parent pom. "I have heard that this is best practice because it enables you to access the db from other future projects. Ex Android app"

What do I need to include in my parent/child pom so that my backend module is reading from the parent repository?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a clarification: _repository_ means here the **database** not some maven repository?

Comment: Yes  - sorry if that was unclear

Comment: Do you have `parent` project as packaging `pom` and child projects have `<parent />` section?

Comment: Yes that is how it is currently configured

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible but not sure because not too familiar how Spring is configured.

In the parent projects `pom.xml` all the main or profile related `<properties />` are usable in child projects also.

With proper filtering you can use properties set in parents `pom.xml` to be set in your child project configuration files.

So for a dummy and abstract (totally Spring configuration unrelated but jsut to show how it could work) example, with

**pom.xml (parent)**

```
<properties>
   <db.url>jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/MyDb</db.url>
   ...
<properties>
```

and

**some configuration / property file**

```
db.url=${db.url}
```

the result for filtering would be

```
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/MyDb
```

See also this filtering related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465001/where-should-i-put-application-configuration-files-for-a-maven-project).

Comment: Please note that the spring-boot-starter-parent module changes default delimiters for resource filtering to `@`. If you use this module in your project, you would need to use `@db.url@` in your application properties